# std::unique_ptr and its effect on matching pointers in STL containers

Tags: c++, stl, unique-ptr

I made a factory class for lights in my game where a function "create" creates a unique_ptr and stores it in a STL vector, so I can collect the light data and send it to a shader, then it returns a reference to that unique_ptr in the vector like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<Light>& create() {
    myVector.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Light>(new Light));
    return &myVector.back();
}
```

However, when I add more lights, the unique_ptr reference (not the raw pointer) gets invalidated because it was referencing the unique_ptr object in the vector.  So, passing the unique_ptr reference after creating it lead to errors.  So, I came up with this solution:

```
std::unique_ptr<Light> create() {
    Light* light = new Light();
    myVector.push_back(light);
    return std::unique_ptr<Light>(light);
}
```

Which solved the invalidation issue, but now, when the unique_ptr went out of scope, it replaced its raw pointer in myVector with the next pointer in the vector.  So, if I had a vector of pointers: [1, 2, 3] then after unique_ptr went out of scope the vector became [2, 2, 3].  Naturally, I didn't want redundant data so I replaced the vector with a STL set.  Now, when the unique_ptr goes out of scope the set finds the redundant data and removes the one copy, so the set correctly contains pointers: [2, 3].  This works and I don't receive any errors, but I don't understand why or how the unique_ptr changes the matching pointer value in the STL container.  Is this expected behavior?  If so, why/how does it work?

PS: I understand that the purpose of a unique_ptr is to make the pointer owned by one single object.  As a result, I prefer having the sole ownership kept in the object that calls the create() function.  So, the factory simply creates the light and stores references to the lights it created for easy collection, though the storage done by the factory itself is just a temporary measure.  However, I love the nature of the STL set automatically being maintained when the unique_ptr automatically releases itself when it goes out of scope.  So, I'd like to keep that generic design, only if it isn't some fluke with the unique_ptr.

Comment: That's not a valid C++ function.  What is the return type?  (It's important)

Comment: Do you mean `return myVector.back().get()`?

Comment: `assert(myVector.size() == 4)`

Comment: @DrewDormann Sorry, wrote it in as sort of pseudo code so forgot that may matter.

Comment: Looks like you need an `std::shared_ptr`…

Comment: This question has nothing to do with unique pointers. It just seems to be about iterator and reference invalidation of standard library containers.

Comment: I can't offer much help, except that the STL container should really own the lifetime of the objects it carries. If that is not the semantics you want, perhaps @TheParamagneticCroissant's suggestion of using `shared_ptr` is what you actually want.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I thought about that, but I didn't like that how I could create a Light object in a block, then leave that block, and the light would still exist in the vector.  Also, if I left the block then I wouldn't be able to remove it from the vector because I lost the variable that held the reference.  I could add something to the destructor to remove it from the vector when it was deleted, but I thought that seemed like a workaround.

Comment: @heyufool1 I don't understand how your second argument is specific to `shared_ptr` – your current solution has the same problem (if you return a raw pointer but store a smart pointer, your object is still alive). However, this starts to smell to me more and more of a design error – if you don't need the object to be in the vector, then why are you storing it in the vector, in first place?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I read that a shared_ptr stores the number of times it's being used as a reference.  So if I have the shared_ptr stored in 2 areas then I thought it would be 2 references, so I have to remove both references until the Light is finally deleted.  However, with the unique_ptr in the 2nd method I used, when the single unique_ptr object goes out of scope, then the light is entirely deleted because it, for whatever reason, updated the vector that also stored the pointer.

Comment: @heyufool1 yes. And you don't want it to be deleted until either the vector or the caller owns it. Hence, `unique_ptr` is not a solution to your problem.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I don't want the vector to own it, it just so happened to be convenient that way in the first method.  I only want the vector so I have a collection of the light data for use with the shader.

Comment: @heyufool1 So the lifetime of the vector is shorter than (or at most as long as) the variable to which you bind return value of your factory function? It's really hard to grasp how you're using this, some sample code would help…

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant The lifetime of the vector is at least the length of the variable(s) in it.  For example, I could add 2 lights, then the collection will have 2 lights.  Then I could delete a light, and it will have 1 light.  Then I could delete the last light and it will be empty, but it'll still be available for adding more lights until the application exits.

Comment: "Then I could delete a light, and it will have 1 light" – in this case, the vector owns the light.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant In the first way of doing it, it was that case, explicitly.  In the second case, it did it automatically which I did not understand because I didn't expect it to, hence why I asked this question.  Turns out it was just a coincidence with an invalid pointer in the container getting converted to a garbage value.

Comment: @heyufool1 yes, it absolutely was a coincidence. If you want an automatically nullable pointer, then you can create a `shared_ptr` and a corresponding `weak_ptr`, and store only the `weak_ptr`s. When the `shared_ptr` is deallocated (i. e. all references to it are removed), then all corresponding `weak_ptr`s will be reset to `nullptr`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Interesting, thanks for the help.  I'm going to convert back to returning a "simple_ptr" using the raw pointer so it simply isn't easily allowed to be deleted, which was my only concern with returning a raw pointer instead of returning a reference to a smart pointer.

Comment: Beware of std::vector: push_back If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers and references related to the container are invalidated. See https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/ section "Iterator validity"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Light>>` is the owner of the `Light`s, there is little use in returning references to these rather than pointers to the `Light`s. The references are only useful if you need to replace the value. I'd just travel in terms of `Light*` or `Light const*` where the objects are used rather than owned. You can get the pointer held by a `std::unique_ptr<T>` with the `get()` method.

Instead of returning a `Light*` you *could* return a `simple_ptr<Light>` where `simple_ptr<T>` essentially just has a constructor taking a `T*` and operators `operator->()` which returns a `T*` and `operator*()` which returns a `T&`:

```
template <typename T>
class simple_ptr {
    T* ptr;
public:
    explicit simple_ptr(T* ptr): ptr(ptr) {}
    T* operator->() const { return this->ptr; }
    T& operator*() const { return *this->ptr; }
};
```

The generated functions just do the Right Thing (i.e. copy the pointer as needed). Without jumping through hoops it wouldn't be possible `delete` this pointer. If you give your `Light` type a custom unary `operator&()` you could make it even harder to explicitly get to the pointer. Tt won't be impossible, though, as you can always call `ptr.operator->()` to get it. However, you should only defend against Murphy, not against Machiavelli.

Comment: That's what I had originally, however I didn't like that when returning a pointer I could still optionally delete it.  I wanted to see if I could remove all possible self-written programming errors.

Comment: @heyufool1: That's called `grep` for `delete` and `new`, and if either of them return non-zero, you've made an error.

Comment: I like that simple_ptr idea.  I really wanted to do it the way of returning the raw pointer but it seemed weird to have a raw pointer, but at the same time I shouldn't delete the raw pointer.  As long as I can't use the standard "delete ptr" then I'm happy.  I think I may adopt that solution, after some more thought.  Thanks for the idea! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to delete the object while either the caller of your factory function **or** the vector has a pointer to it, why not use an `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Because I want one owner, the vector was purely used as a way to keep a collection of the light data so I can interact with the shader.

Answer (score 1):

You're contradicting the design of `std::unique_ptr` by trying to have multiple copies of it.

This could be solved by using [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead.

```
std::shared_ptr<Light> create() {
    myVector.push_back(std::make_shared<Light>());
    return myVector.back();
}
```

Or if you want your vector to be primarily responsible for the lifetime of these lights, return a [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/weak_ptr), which knows when it's dangling.

```
std::weak_ptr<Light> create() {
    myVector.push_back(std::make_shared<Light>());
    return myVector.back();
}
```

Comment: I didn't want multiple copies, I wanted a reference to the original, which broke when the reference got invalidated.  In the second version, I wanted one unique pointer, and it just so happened that the vector was auto-maintained so I thought I could stick with it.  I need a collection of the lights for communication with the shader, so no matter what I need a vector of data and no matter what I need a pointer to modify the data.  Hence the unique_ptr and the collection of pointers.  Though I didn't know about weak_ptr which I'll look into :)

Comment: Basically, the vector was there only so I have a way to collect the light's data, nothing to do with ownership.  Granted in that case the vector did have ownership, which I handled by having a function called destroy() where I pass the light's unique_ptr reference and it removed it from the vector.

Comment: @heyufool1 if you haven't decided the ownership rules for these lights, that's why you're having trouble with smart pointers.

Comment: Well, originally I wanted the ownership to be the vector.  But it felt like I was forced to scrap that idea because I couldn't reference the light in the vector without invalidating it.  I know I could use get() to return the raw pointer, but it seemed like everywhere I read said this was bad practice.  Which, the only reason I switched to smart pointers in the first place was because of "bad practice".

Comment: @heyufool1 good luck.  I think any of the three answers provided here solve the problem you described in your question.

Comment: They do, with pros and cons to each.  However, no one answered my original question which, while may be irrelevant now, I'm still very curious about.  Why would deleting the unique_ptr change the same pointer in the STL container it was stored in?  Does the container automatically handle deleted pointers some how?

Comment: @heyufool1 you did not show code that demonstrates that happening, so no one can say how it happened.

Comment: I did though, that's why I'm confused.  I created a light and assigned the return value to a variable.  Then when the variable went out of scope it deleted itself, because it's a unique_ptr.  Then when I go to look at the vector, it also removed (rather copied another existing value into the spot where the old pointer was).  That's all, I never touched the vector besides using push_back in create(), and I never touched the unique_ptr itself, only the raw pointer.

Comment: @heyufool1 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum

Comment: to be fair, it wouldn't have become like this if people read my post and helped answering the only two questions in there, which are completely unrelated to how I handled a unique_ptr in the design sense: "...I don't understand why or how the unique_ptr changes the matching pointer value in the STL container. Is this expected behavior? If so, why/how does it work?"  Instead everyone questioned my use of the unique_ptr and such, which while bad use I'll admit that, was not the point of my question.  Regardless, I'm trying a test program to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Smart pointers are about solving the resource ***ownership*** problem. This doesn't mean you always use shared_ptr and never use "raw" pointers.

It appears that you want to have a vector of lights where this vector is responsible for the resources. For that you don't even need pointers because the vector handles the pointers internally.

```
vector<Light> myVector;
```

You can get a handle to this resource from the vector or from the return of this create function.

```
const Light& create() {
      Light light;
      myVector.push_back(light);
      return myVector.back();
}
```

What is the consumer of this resource allowed to do? Can it delete the light?

And what guarantees can the vector make to the consumers?  Will these pointers be used passed the lifetime of the list.

- Passing around unique_ptr means passing around the ownership.
- Creating shared_ptr's means that when the last reference is deleted, the resource is cleaned up.
- weak_ptr's can be used for observers that don't care if the resource is cleaned up.
- raw pointers and references don't care about anything. But if you are just acquiring a handle in place and read and writing to that instance, you don't need to deal with the overhead of a share_ptr.

Comment: Beware of std::vector: push_back If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers and references related to the container are invalidated. See https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/ section "Iterator validity"